How do I update solr.xml to given read/write/delete permissions to backup directory so backups work?
I am trying to start a Solr backup using the following API call: https://{server}:{port}/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name={backupId}&collection={collectionName}&location={SolrHomeDir}
I get an error as the paths {solrHomeDir}\{backupId}\{collectionName}\zk_backup_0 and {solrHomeDir}\{backupId}\{collectionName}\share_backup_metadata do not exist.
I chose the {solrHomeDir} so I don't have to update allowPaths in solr.xml but maybe this is a mistake.
If I create the missing directories the backup works perfectly.
I found the following comment on this question: Does anyone here have a clue why Solr 9.1 is not starting a backup?

I solved the problem. The actual issue was that you have to update the policy file on Solr install etc directory (security.policy). Given read,write and delete permission to the backup directory, it did the magic.

How do I do this so Solr itself is able to create the backup structure required?
